# Merge jq output into a comma separated string and new line

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I'm trying to extract specific columns from this JSON file (which is probably incorrectly formatted).

Here is a data sample:

```json
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ddb1e4a9a0881572c000008" }, "aggregates" : { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e0cc19ccd62f55ff9000006" }, "comments" : 0, "followers" : 1610, "following" : 92, "likes" : 8, "mig" : 1, "ntf" : 294, "posts" : 1, "yaf" : 1 }, "created_at" : { "$date" : 1306205770619 }, "devices" : [ "ios2:b54e0199cbcf73ba602bd11365b8bd3a7024796b", "ios2:7511337bea3c2378533fedceb156fae0a4a12bfe" ], "email" : "abc@example.edu", "email_verified" : true, "fb_info" : { "ext_user_id" : "123", "ext_access_token" : "tok_id", "ext_token_expr" : { "$date" : 1448577425000 }, "ext_username" : null, "fetched_at" : { "$date" : 1306205770610 }, "ext_permissions" : { "email" : 1, "offline_access" : 1, "contact_email" : 1, "user_friends" : 1, "publish_actions" : 1, "public_profile" : 1 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "null" }, "ext_token_secret" : null }, "fb_user_id" : "123", "first_name" : "null", "gender" : "male", "last_name" : "null", "last_viewed_notification" : { "$oid" : "51525c4b4b807539ab002de4" }, "lns" : 1258, "profile" : { "city" : "San Francisco", "state" : "California", "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e6a9536cd62f5543b00000b" } }, "pv2" : { "desc" : "San Francisco, California" }, "reg_method" : "fb", "seg" : { "sup" : "I" }, "status" : "active", "username" : "null" }
```

There's multiple columns like that without any [] 3 lines in same format starting with { & end with }

So I have used `jq` in this example with adding commas between each field data. My command is:

```bsh
cat example.json example.json example.json |
  jq -r '.status,.city,.gender' | paste -sd,
```

(The sample data is printed three times to reproduce the result I get using the real data).

The output was:

```
active,null,male,active,null,male,active,null,male
```

There should be a new line after each extracted data I don't now how to do that each time. I try to extract them I got all data in one line.
The correct output should be with new line of each data.

```
active,null,male
active,null,male
active,null,male
```

Comment: Do you have three such lines in your input file? I'm afraid that is not quite clear.

Comment: I don't think this is how I would approach the issue (I'd probably try to make `jq` alone produce the desired output), but you seem to simply need `paste -d, - - -` (other things equal).

Comment: Using your example, I don't get the repeated output you suggest; I just get a single instance of `active,null,male`. Can you provide an input sample that actually maps on to desired multiple lines of output, and if not how are we supposed to "know" at what point the split is to occur?

Comment: I'd use `jq -r '[.status,.city,.gender]|@csv'`

Comment: I took the liberty to change your example command because it didn't look clear to other users. Please feel free to revert/improve it if needed. Also, must the output look literally as shown? E.g. can't it include double quotes? Does "null" need to be printed or could it be rendered as an empty string instead?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) feature of `jq`. You can output a string where the placeholders `\()` can contain selected values, and the rest is your surrounding text, all this inside double quotes. For your example:

```
jq -r '"\(.status),\(.city),\(.gender)"' example.json{,,}
active,null,male
active,null,male
active,null,male
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ cat file file file | mlr --j2c -N unsparsify --fill-with null -f status,city,gender then cut -o -f status,city,gender
active,null,male
active,null,male
active,null,male
```

This uses Miller (`mlr`) to read the JSON in the question three times in a row. Each time it starts by filling in any empty or missing values in the fields `status`, `city`, or `gender` with the string `null` using the `unsparsify` operation.  It then uses `cut` to extract those same fields.  The output will be a header-less CSV file, and any fields requiring quoting will be quoted.